# Passing an entity to a controller via symfony route using twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

When I pass an entity to a twig file, I want to pass that entity back to a controller and rerender prior to database persistence.  entity is a variable passed from the controller originally.

Twig:

```
<a href='{{ path('groupitem_new',{'entity' : entity}) }}'>Link Name</a>
```

This does not work.  The entity is not passed.

How do I pass an entity via a symfony route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can not.

`path` and `url` functions in twig are for generating URL(s) not calling a controller's action.

you should instead [embedd a controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) in twig with {% render %} tag like this:

```
{# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}
{% render url('some_route', { 'entity': entity }) %}
```

note that `url` function in render tag is somehow different to `url` function you use to generate a URl, this one is used to call a controller's action and is introduced in symfony from 2.0.20/2.1.5 version for a security fix. older syntax was like this:

```
{# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}
{% render 'AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show' with { 'entity': entity } %}
```

in which 'AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show' is called [`logical controller name`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#controller-naming-pattern).

also remember that at least you should return an empty response in your controller's action:

```
// src/Acme/BlogBundle/Controller/BlogController.php
.
public function showAction(){
    .
    .
    .
    return new Response();
}
.
```

also add `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;` to top of controller file.

Comment: Well that answers the question.  How I deal with this new found power is another story entirely.